# My c++ program gives correct results in codeblocks but gives incorrect results in visual basic 2005 express edition

Tags: c++

My c++ program  gives correct results in codeblocks but gives incorrect results in visual basic 2005 express edition. Can anyone please guide me as to what I am doing wrong :) Thank you :)
Here is my program for finding factorial using a function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fact( int a)
{
    if (a>1)
    return a*fact(a-1);
}
int  main()
{
    cout<<"Enter a number to find its factorial : ";
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Factorial of "<<a<<" is "<<fact(a)<<endl<<endl;
}
```

Result in codeblocks

```
Enter a number to find its factorial : 5
Factorial of 5 is 120
```

Result in visual basic 2005 express edition

```
Enter a number to find its factorial : 5
Factorial of 5 is -96
```

Comment: What do you return if `a <= 1`?  Oops.

Comment: in codeblocks ,making a<=1 just returns the number entered for finding factorial, and in vb express 2005 it gives unexpected results :)

Comment: Please read my answer.  The problem is that you are failing to return a value from a function that is supposed to return a value.  Regardless of what the function does, that is undefined behavior.

Comment: yes right :) when the IF condition isnt true, still it must return a value, which it wasnt earlier :) now with return 1, it does that :) thank you :)

Comment: Yes, you should return a value for all of your function's return paths.  Also, your compiler should have warned you of this (turn up your compiler warning settings if you didn't see such a warning).

Comment: ok i will :) thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of your code is undefined.

If `a <= 1` in the `fact` function, you failed to return a value.  Failure to return a value results in undefined behavior, thus the different results you're seeing.

The correction should be:

```
int fact( int a)
{
    if (a>1)
       return a*fact(a-1);
    return 1; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you PaulMcKenzie :) now it works fine in vb 2005 :)

Comment: You may not still be seeing the issue.  It doesn't matter the compiler used -- the behavior or your original program was undefined.  Undefined means that any answer could have been displayed, the program could have crashed, and yes, even the "right" answer may have been printed.  The way to prevent that is to write your code so that the behavior becomes well-defined.

Comment: ok :) thank you :)